# resending information problem

Tags: php

i've a search bar from where users can search for videos..
after the search, the user goes on to click and watch a video(from the search result)..when the user hits the browser's back button it displays the following

> To display this page, Firefox must
>   send information that will repeat any
>   action (such as a search or order
>   confirmation) that was performed
>   earlier.

instead of just showing the results..
i just want to display the results of search when the user hits back..is it something related to cache?
thankx..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferably, change your search form's method to `get`, or use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

That message is displayed because POST data needs to be resent to re-render the page.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want that, you can use GET instead of POST for your form method.

ie, you should use something like this :

```
<form action"yourpage.php" method="get">
    ...
</form>
```

instead of :

```
<form action"yourpage.php" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

This way, the parameters used in the form will be sent in the URL, and not by POST, and users will be able to :

- use back with no problem, independantly of the browser's cache
- bookmark the result page (which is nice ^^ )

And I should add that, in theory :

- POST has to be used when you want to create/modify data
- and GET has to be used when you want to... well, get, data.

When searching for something via a search form, your users are not creating nor modifying data : they are asking for data -- so, your form should use the GET method.

Answer (score 1):

To remove this problem, replace the existing `top.location.reload()` or `parent.location.reload();` with `top.location.href=top.location.href;`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a cache issue. The problem is that you are using `POST` to submit the search form. There are a couple of solutions.

- The better one is change the form to use `GET`. You can do that by setting its `method` attribute like

  ```
  <form method="get" action="search.php">
  ```
- The other, if you fear that the search query will get way too long you can save the search with some form of id and then redirect to a page that fetches this search id and shows the result. Redirecting can be done with

  ```
  header('Location: show_search.php?id=' . $searchId);
  ```